# Can anyone explain what happened here?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

Here is a transaction that was made by contract to create an nft in another contract.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfa97c3476aa8aeac662dae0cc3f0d3da48472ff4e7c55d0e305901ec37a2f704

This is hacked contract :

https://etherscan.io/address/0x14e0a1f310e2b7e321c91f58847e98b8c802f6ef

Answer (score 1):

Nothing strange, no hacking at all. Or at least, we don't really know ;) See below.

The sender wanted to mint 66 NFTs from that contract, so they have in general two options:

- sending 66 transactions to mint 66 tokens, sending 0.4 ethers for each
- creating a smart contract to do the same, spending 26,4 ethers but starting the operation with a single transaction

They choose the latter to save about **~0.5 ethers** in fees. Not bad ;)

Please note that you need to carefully calculate the gas costs before trying to do this kind of operation. Each transaction starts from a cost of 21.000 gas, but in any case you can do some math here to see how much gas savings was done.

- Contract + bulk minting: 899.127 (deploy) + 8.797.333 (mint) = 9.696.460 gas
- 66 minting transactions: 185.331 * 66 = 12.231.846 gas
- Savings: 2.535.386 gas

At 200 Gwei per gas (price they set for the txs) it's about ~0.5 ether saved.

Update:

In this specific case, there are some checks and controls the senders need to surpass to mint more than 1 token per address with this contract. Being the owner of the contract allows them to do so.

Looking briefly at the contract code it seems the owner of the contract was changed to 0xe0f7204f04b060715f858ba8ae357f57e5494d18 a [few blocks before](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x70977789e783b1d04d8d3054172fa22174f11ff401e4f466fceac0546749d377#eventlog) sending that minting transaction, during the deployment of the intermediate contract.

Because of how the process is hidden, it can seem like a hack, but we don't know if HB owner and 0xe0f7204f04b060715f858ba8ae357f57e5494d18 are the same. So, never trust owned smart contract ;)

Asked [here](https://twitter.com/giuseppebertone/status/1489199359287828486) anyway, let's see.

Update 2:

It seems HB is advertising 0xE5ef688FDC204cE2Ff25DDc6D277077e1873c9b4 as its own address for token giveaways.

Comment: I'm surprised how he did it without being on the whitle list, there is a limit of 1 nft per addres

Comment: I know that it possible if you are owner of NFT contract but i dont know how i to this. Maybe you have some docs to read about it ?

Comment: Looking briefly at the contract code it seems the owner of the contract was not set correctly during contract deployment, and it changed to 0xe0f7204f04b060715f858ba8ae357f57e5494d18 (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x70977789e783b1d04d8d3054172fa22174f11ff401e4f466fceac0546749d377#eventlog) a few blocks before sending that minting transaction, during the deployment of the intermediate contract. Because how the process is hidden, it seems a hack, but we don't know if HB owner and 0xe0f7204f04b060715f858ba8ae357f57e5494d18 are the same, so... Never trust owned smart contract ;)

Comment: I added some info to the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think this was a hack. Attacker use reentrancy on single function

Comment: Not necessarily. As ower, they can modify the limit, call the mintNFT, and then set the limit again back to 1 in a single transaction. Or they can add themself as partners, use partnersMintMultiple and remove themself from partners. Again, as an owner, you can do essentially whatever you want :D I found on Discord they are advertising the 0xE5ef688FDC204cE2Ff25DDc6D277077e1873c9b4 as their own address for giveaways, so it's difficult to consider this as a hack.